# Should homework questions be allowed? Many questions are being closed as "homework" but there is no policy or consensus against

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics, questions, close-reasons

Refer to [this question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/12704/pv-homework-question).  It's homework, and clearly disclosed as such. Somebody flagged the question, stating *"I'm assuming homework questions aren't allowed here."*

Got me thinking that we haven't actually established a clear policy on homework questions.

UPDATE: Here's a more recent occurrence and perhaps better example where the question, IMHO, is apropos to personal finance, but it is being voted-to-close because it is homework: [Solving for mortgage payment amount and its deduction on the total principal?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/30966/solving-for-mortgage-payment-amount-and-its-deduction-on-the-total-principal)

**Should homework questions be permitted on the site?** If yes, under what circumstances? If no, why not?

Answer (score 12):

From a comment on the homework question being discussed:

> At electronics.SE we allow homework questions as long as it is still
>   an acceptable question as far as the sites standards are concerned. So
>   essentially, remove any references to it being a homework question,
>   and if it is still a good question then it can stand. The problem with
>   this question is an answer could simply be "Yes" and nothing else. It
>   is good to see effort on the part of the OP, but it also has to have
>   room for a good answer. – Kellenjb

The first example cited is a bad question because the only valid answers are "yes" or "no", not because it's homework.  "yes" or "no" do not add anything to the community.

Answer (score 9):

If the question has value beyond the homework, it may be worth keeping. I liked that the OP of the first example cited shared an equation to solve an otherwise sophisticated problem. I confirmed I got the answer he did using a spreadsheet.

To answer you specifically, the concept of 'good question' is probably subjective, and we're back to group rule, voting to close/delete.

The current question regarding mortgage calculation is legit, in my opinion, although the homework aspect puts a slight spin on it. He wants to understand the calculation vs just being led to a calculator or App that gives a result.

Answer (score 7):

Like any good question on SE, it should really be about the amount of effort.  If they cut and paste their homework question, I would close and eventually delete that.  If they cut and paste, show their answer and their process, then I would try to answer it.  They don't have to give the right answer; even a mistake can be helpful to teach.

### Proposed rules guidelines for homework type questions:

- Is it on topic?
- Does it show effort?
- Are they looking for clarification on an answer they propose?
- Is it labeled or identified as homework?

I would say the first two are paramount, and failure to met those standards should have the question closed; the second two are just good practice to encourage people to help.

Under these guidelines; the first example is awesome for our site, the second example should be put on hold until some work is shown.

In a nutshell, ***we should clarify, expand, and confirm or correct homework that has shown effort.***

Comment: Whatever the rule is that gets accepted, we should edit the help to point to it, so lets make the answer nice looking.

Comment: How do we feel about the homework tag? I know SO has banned it, should we?

Comment: @JohnFx - I don't like it as a tag.  I feel tags should be about the topic, not why the topic came up.

Answer (score -3):

Personally, I believe that a website like stackexchange is about getting opinions. I think that peer to peer interaction makes the question rich and shows multiple ways of approaching the subject.

Given this, I believe that any kind of question ought to be allowed.

Comment: No, actually, it is exactly the opposite. Questions soliciting *opinions* are closed.

Comment: Ah. Okay then - Makes sense.